# Problems with DLLs

Tags: c, dll

guys! I somehow found an easier to understand tutorial about DLLs in C, but now I can't seem to get out of this one problem.

I've created this simple program that uses a DLL. I intend to call a function named "HelloWorld()" in the DLL and see if it would show up a I hoped for.

"dllmain.c"

```
/* Replace "dll.h" with the name of your header */
#include "dll.h"
#include <windows.h>

DLLIMPORT void HelloWorld()
{
        printf("HAI!");
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL,DWORD fdwReason,LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    switch(fdwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        {
            break;
        }
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        {
            break;
        }
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        {
            break;
        }
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    /* Return TRUE on success, FALSE on failure */
    return TRUE;
}
```

"dll.h"

```
#ifndef _DLL_H_
#define _DLL_H_

#if BUILDING_DLL
#define DLLIMPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLIMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

DLLIMPORT void HelloWorld();

#endif
```

"main.c" (The executable)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "dll.h"
#include <windows.h>

main()
{
    HelloWorld();
        getch();
}
```

This is the problem:

Error Message
    {C:...\Documents\DLLTest\main.o

```
main.c:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `__imp_HelloWorld'}

{C:\...\Documents\DLLTest\collect2.exe  [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

Can someone tell me why this appears?! Thanks in advance!}
```

Oh, and by the way, this was made with DevC++ TDM-GCC 4.7.1 64-bit Release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compile the `main.c` with `-L. -ldllmain` (`.` means the current directory where the DLL is located). For example I have these files in the current directory:

```
> dir
...
01/18/2014  05:53 PM    <DIR>          .
01/18/2014  05:53 PM    <DIR>          ..
01/18/2014  05:48 PM               191 dll.h
01/18/2014  05:49 PM               615 dllmain.c
01/18/2014  05:50 PM               150 main.c
...
>
```

compile the DLL and then compile `main.c` and link it with `dllmain.dll`:

```
> gcc -Wall dllmain.c -shared -o dllmain.dll
> gcc -Wall main.c -L. -ldllmain
```

now you are good to go:

```
> dir
...
01/18/2014  05:53 PM            29,141 a.exe
01/18/2014  05:48 PM               191 dll.h
01/18/2014  05:49 PM               615 dllmain.c
01/18/2014  05:53 PM            26,466 dllmain.dll
01/18/2014  05:50 PM               150 main.c
...
> a.exe
HAI!
>
```

Comment: Can I ask how this can be done? I mean, where do I find this kind of option in DevC++?

Comment: @Wix I guess it uses gcc as compiler? look at [this page](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/en/ide_guide/dev-cpp.html) of how to pass parameters to the "linker", pass `-ldllmain`, after it there is "library directories" where you pass the directory where dllmain.dll is located.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get it. Do you do this with the MS Command Prompt or is there an easier way to do this with the Dev-C++ GUI?

Comment: @Wix I really don't have dev-c++, I use gcc via command line. Look at this page -[C Programming/Using a Compiler](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Using_a_Compiler)- on installing and configuring gcc.

Comment: Aw, man! Thanks! That worked! Thank you so much for your help! Now I can be more advanced than my classmates LOL.

Comment: Um, sorry about this but, what if I want to associate multiple dlls to a single executable file? What should be done?

Comment: @Wix No different, you can pass them as `-ldllmain1 -ldllmain2 -lfoo -lbar ... etc`. See gcc linking options for more information: ([Options for Linking](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) | [Options for Directory Search](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html)).

Comment: Can I ask how you can compile an executable with dlls in a separate directory?

Comment: @Wix Use the `-L` switch followed by the directory to where that DLl is located, you can have more than one `-L` switch.

Answer (score 0):

You need add compiled dll library (*.lib or something similar) to your project

Click on the Projects ->"Project Options"->"Parameters" and in section Linker add library